# how can i highlight a row when date is older than yesterday

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery and JavaScript. I have a small question. Let's say i have a HTML table like the following

```
<?php 
    include 'dbconnect.php'; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Comments";            

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo '<div>no comments were set up</div>'; 
    } 
    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

    echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
    echo "<table id='myTable' border='1'><tr>";
    // printing table headers
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
    {
        $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);                       
        echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";                     
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    // printing table rows
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
        // of $row to $cell variable
        foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        //delete button
        echo "<td><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></td>";
        //checkbox button
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='Highlight' onclick='highlight(this)'></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);             
?>
```

I want to check if the date in the 8th column is older than a day the row should be highlighted. How can I proceed.

i found a code but this is not working:

```
           function checkdate(){
           $('#myTable  tr td').each(function () {
           var dtTd = new Date($(this).html());
           var dtNew = new Date();
          // 15 minutes is 900000 milliseconds
        // getTime() doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime
           if (dtTd.getTime() - dtNew.getTime() < 900000 && dtNew < dtTd) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            } else {
             if (dtNew > dtTd) {
          $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
            }
            }
            });
             }
```

Comment: Read the date in 8th column, compare, if older then use another css class

Comment: you need to highlight this td  `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' value='Highlight' onclick='highlight(this)'></td>";` ?

Comment: Why would you do this in jquery when you can do so at the time of generation in php?

Comment: the language doesn't matter, i don't know how to call the 8th column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach($row as $cell)
{
    if($cell['date'] < $date)
    {
        // for date less then today's date
    }
    else
    {
        // for others date
    }
}
```

Comment: if($cell['date'] < $date)
{
        echo '<td style="coor:yellow"></td>';
}
put this in if block

Comment: this is not working . i have the table name, the  column header i want to search the value from and it should be older than yesterday. thanks

Comment: the code inserted is: $date = new Date('Y-m-d-h-m');
foreach($row as $cell)
{
    if($cell['CommentsDate']-$date <24 )
    {
        // for date less then today's date
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
} not working :(